Are there problems with using Cuid v1 and Cuid v2 in the same Database?
I recently read that Cuid v1 has been deprecated and replaced by Cuid v2. We currently use a PostgreSQL database where all of our ID's use Cuid v1. We are planning to change some parts of the table structures and relations. We are considering starting by using Cuid v2 for the new tables with the improved structure and later on change the IDs of the old tables into Cuid v2. Due to our current project timeline and the tasks, we have in the backlog, the change of all the other ID's to Cuid v2 will be much later.
My questions are:

What are the potential problems of using Cuidv2 as an ID in a database where all other tables use Cuid v1?
What are the potential problems of using Cuid v1 and Cuid v2 in the same table? This is for the case where we decide to change all new rows to use Cuid v2 but haven't yet changed all the old row ID's to Cuid v1.
Is it worth to change from Cuid v1 to Cuid v2 if they are only used as IDs for table rows?

I think they should work as both of them are string based ID's with similar lengths, but I haven't seen any information on this yet, so I want to make sure I'm aware of potential problems before I try it and also want to educate myself on best practices when doing ID version changes across a database or segmenting it into different phases of changing the database ID's.

you might consider asking your question on the pgsql-general mailing list. "many of the developers monitor [this mailing list]", according to: https://www.postgresql.org/list/

I was not aware of that list, thank you
